# Whitelist Apps With Android Device Owner

Tags: android

I need to setup an environment in an android device where only white listed apps are allowed to launch. The environment should

- prevent user from installing new app and uninstalling existing app
- prevent access to settings
- prevent access to file directory

The Owner App are supposed to allow

- download of white listed APK from a designated server within it's network
- user can update white listed APK by downloading and installing it
- user can launch multiple white listed app

I have looked through Android's Device Ownership and Screen Pinning references and APIs but couldn't find a solution to my above stated problem. Any pointers?

What do you think of this? http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/

UPDATE:
Well, I've decided to use vendor like MobileIron. Thanks for the input regardlessly =)

Comment: For this type of permissions you need to have root access if I'm not wrong.

Comment: you better create a custom rom

Comment: Thanks guys! But I am restricted so I cannot root the device. What do you think of this http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/